# How to convert a Count Min sketch to a Bloom Filter?

Tags: python, c#, math, statistics

I am using pyprobables library to create Count min sketch and bloom filter. First I created count min sktech. Then I am trying to convert count min sketch to bloom filter. If the count in count min sketch  is more than threshold, then I am trying to set 1 in the bloom filter. How can it be realized and done? Since I already have count min sketch and the keys are not stored, how does the addition in the bloom filter can be achieved?

I used the bloom filter estimated elements equal to width of count min sketch. But I find difficulty to add items to the bloom filter. The hashing functions used are same as well in both of the library. I am looking for theoretical as well as practical implementation of conversion of Count min sketch to Bloom filter.

Here is how I used pyproables library to create Count min sketch (CMS) and bloom filter:

```
> from probables import CountMinSketch,BloomFilter
> cms.add('Google',3) 
> cms.add('Facebook',5)
>  cms.add('Twitter',5)
> cms.add('Amazon',4)

> bloom=BloomFilter(est_elements=cms.width, false_positive_rate=0.01)
> bloom.add('AI')
> bloom.add('Google') 
> bloom.add('Meta')
```

Since I already created a CMS and I donot have access to the key from CMS, how can I convert it to the bloom filter. if the count in the count min sketch is more than 3 then add it to the bloom filter otherwise donot add.

Answer (score 0):

```
from probables import (CountMinSketch)
from probables import (BloomFilter)

threshold = 3

keyValues = {
    'Google': 3, 
    'Facebook':6, 
    'Twitter': 5, 
    'Amazon': 4
}

cms = CountMinSketch(width=1000, depth=threshold)
for i in range(threshold):
    key = list(keyValues.items())[i][0]
    value = keyValues[list(keyValues.keys())[i]] 
    cms.add(key, value)

print(cms.check('Amazon')) # prints 0 because 'Amazon' is not inserted in the cms

blm=BloomFilter(est_elements=cms.width, false_positive_rate=0.01)
for key in keyValues.keys():
    if cms.check(key) == 0:
        blm.add(key)

print(str(blm.elements_added) + ' element added!') # prints: 1 element added!
```

Edit:

```
    threshold = 3
     
    # Assume cms is already created

    # Create a Bloom Filter with the same parameters as the CountMinSketch
    bloom = BloomFilter(est_elements=cms.width, false_positive_rate=0.01)
        
    Approach1:
    for key in cms.keys():
         if cms.check(key) > threshold:
             bloom.add(key)

    Approach2:
    # Iterate over each cell of the CMS
    for i in range(cms.width):
        for j in range(cms.depth):
            if cms.check((i, j)) > threshold:
                # Hash the index using the same hash functions used by the CMS and the Bloom Filter
                index = bloom.hash((i, j))
                bloom.add(index)

        
    print('Facebook' in bloom)  # True
```

In the *Approach1* we use the same hash functions as the Bloom Filter to map the corresponding index to the Bloom Filter, and add the key to it.

The *Approach2* can be more efficient than iterating over all the cells of the Count-Min Sketch since it only selects keys that are likely to be present in the Bloom Filter.

Note that the accuracy of the Bloom Filter will depend on the threshold used in the Count-Min Sketch:

- a higher threshold -> fewer false positives in the Bloom Filter but may also exclude some true positives.
- a lower threshold -> more false positives but may also include more true positives.

---

Or you create a method that converts CMS to BloomFilter as follows:

```
import math
import random

class CountMinSketch:
    def __init__(self, width, depth):
        self.width = width
        self.depth = depth
        self.table = [[0] * width for i in range(depth)]
        self.hash_funcs = [lambda x: hash(str(i) + x) % self.width for i in range(depth)]
    
    def update(self, key, count=1):
        for i in range(self.depth):
            index = self.hash_funcs[i](key)
            self.table[i][index] += count
            
    def query(self, key):
        return min(self.table[i][self.hash_funcs[i](key)] for i in range(self.depth))

def bloom_filter_params(false_pos_rate, num_items):
    width = int(math.ceil((num_items * math.log(false_pos_rate)) / math.log(1.0 / (pow(2.0, math.log(2.0)))))) # width of the Bloom filter
    depth = int(math.ceil(math.log(1.0 / false_pos_rate) / math.log(2.0))) # depth of the Bloom filter
    num_hash_funcs = int((width / num_items) * math.log(2.0)) # number of hash functions
    return width, depth, num_hash_funcs

def cms_to_bloom(cms, false_pos_rate, num_items):
    width, depth, num_hash_funcs = bloom_filter_params(false_pos_rate, num_items)
    bloom_filter = [False] * width
    for key in cms.keys():
        count = cms.query(key)
        prob = 1.0 - pow(1.0 - (1.0 / width), count * num_hash_funcs)
        for i in range(num_hash_funcs):
            index = hash(str(i) + key) % width
            if random.random() < prob:
                bloom_filter[index] = True
    return bloom_filter

# example usage
cms = CountMinSketch(100, 5)
cms.update("Google", 3)
cms.update("Facebook", 6)
cms.update("Twitter", 5)
bloom_filter = cms_to_bloom(cms, 0.01, 3)
print(bloom_filter)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your work. But here was my requirement, I already have a count min sketch created  and  has no longer access to the keys. Then I need to convert it to the bloom filter. I know without key the conversion would be difficult. It's  for my thesis and I need to implement the prototype where it is basically saying count min sketch is created and then the prunning is done by setting threshold removing bad items .  For faster access the CMS is converted to bloom filter. So, how can this be realized, the conversion from CMS to bloom ? Any idea, if CMS is already created.

Comment: Check above edit section for updates.

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed answer. The CMS does not have cms.keys() function to extract the keys from the cms. Due to this, the approach 2 does not seem suitable. If cms stores the keys then it would not be a problem to implement the approach 2. Same applies for the approach 3 where you are using cms.keys().